# How to get a precise ping measurment

Tags: windows, networking

Currently the windows ping command returns a value of milliseconds that is an integer.

I would like to get a very accurate measurement lets say 4 digits after the point.

Are there any tools that do that?

Comment: Nope. The master clock of the internet only has millisecond resolution.  Honestly, though, you could write your own ping that utilizes finer resolution. What are you doing that require such fine precision?

Comment: Are you are trying to use ping to get response times on your network?  If you are crossing networks i.e. the Internet the time is inherently inaccurate.

Comment: Ping only measures the ICMP time, and that has nothing to do with the time for TCP, UDP or any protocol other than ICMP, which is usually quite different than other protocols.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

hrPing does microsecond level accuracy round trip ping timing: [hrPing](http://www.cfos.de/en/ping/ping.htm)

For a great list of alternatives that do microsecond ping round trip timing on Windows, see the following web site:

[Accurate (microsecond level) ping utilities for Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20101020073701/https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/downloads/icmp-ping-dos-microsecond-179371.html)

Comment: How the heck does that pull off finer resolution that the system clock itself?

Comment: @Matt, there's no magic happening here. Standard ping may in fact use the high precision clock and just round or truncate digits that are not interesting in the typical case.

Comment: Unfortunately, standard Windows ping just uses GetTickCount() and thus has a resolution of about 15ms. hrPING uses the RDTSC instruction or the performance counter and thus has a much higher resolution in usecs (10e-6 secs).

Comment: ur link is invalid .. 2nd one