# Low latency/high performance network (ethernet) messaging

Tags: windows, linux, performance, network-programming

#### Background

I want to create a test application to test the network performance of different systems. To do this I plan to have that machine send out Ethernet frames over a private (otherwise non-busy) network to another machine (or device) that simply receives the message and sends it back. The sending application will record total roundtrip time (among other things).

**The purpose** of the tests is to see how a particular **system (OS + components etc.) performs** when it comes to networking traffic. This is illustrated as machine A in the picture below. Note that I'm **not interested in** the performance of the **networking infrastructure** (switches, cables etc) - I'm trying to test the performance of network traffic inside Machine A (i.e from when it hits the network card until it reaches user space)

We will (try to) measure all kind of things, one thing is the total roundtrip of the message but also things like interrupt latency of Machine A, general driver overhead etc. Machine A will be a real-time system. But to support these tests, I need a separate machine that can bounce back messages and in other ways add network stimuli to the tested system. This separate machine is Machine B in the picture below and is what this question is about.

[image: General overview of my test system]

#### My problem

I want to develop an application that can receive and return these messages with as consistent (and preferably low) latency as possible. I'm hoping to get latencies that are consistent within a few microseconds at least. For simplicity, I'd like to do this on a general purpose OS like Windows or Linux but I'm open for other suggestions. There will be no other load (CPU or otherwise) on the machine besides the operating system and my test application.

I've thought of the following approaches:

- A normal application running in user space with a high priority
- A thread running in kernel space to avoid the userspace/kernelspace transitions
- An of-the-shelf device that already does this (I haven't found one though)

#### Questions

Are there any other approaches or perhaps frameworks that already does this? What else do I need to think of to gain a consistent and low latency? What approach is recommended?

Comment: Q: "What else do I need to think of to gain a consistent and low latency?"  A: Kernel execution (linux) / Driver execution (windows).  That said, could you clarify the limits of latency you care about and how you are going to use the information you get?  It isn't always practical to be "as precise as possible", you may find it easier for your measurements to be  "good enough"

Comment: To reach the lowest possible latency, consider implementing this in an FPGA. You don't need a processor, just a MAC and some logic to rewrite the packet header before resending. There are evaluation boards with FPGA and PHY that you could start with.

Comment: @Mike: Good point. I'm honestly not sure what numbers I could expect and I'm prepared to work with what the solution/system can give me. Although it would be nice if the latencies were consistent within a few microseconds. I've no idea if that is possible since I've never done this before - in fact, that kind of input would be very valuable as an answer to the question

Comment: @IsakSavo, could you clarify how you are going to use the information you get?  There are already canned embedded systems to measure and archive network latency within microseconds; however, I need to understand your application to assist

Comment: What about just using `hrPing`? see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3951875/288747 and http://www.cfos.de/en/ping/ping.htm

Comment: @MikePennington: Alright, I added some more information on what we're trying to measure. Those embedded systems you talk about sounds interesting. Maybe you can elaborate a bit on those in an answer?

Comment: @Seph: thanks for the tip. hrPing may be useful in some of the tests we're planning.

Comment: @IsakSavo - I've just heard of a new product called UltraMessaging which can provide 7,000,000 messages per second throughput with Java, C++ or C# clients. Crikey.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to test the internal performance of Machine A, but "need a separate machine"; yet, you don't want to test network infrastructure performance.

You know much more about your requirements than I do; however, if I was testing network infrastructure in Machine A, I would set up my test like this:

[image: Looped Machine]

There are couple of reasons for this:

- You can use an Ethernet loopback cable to simulate the "pong" function performed by Machine B
- Eliminating transit through infrastructure you don't care about is almost always a better solution when measuring performance

If you use this test method, be sure to note these points:

- Ethernet performs a signal to noise test on the copper before it sets up a link.  If you make your loopback bends too tight, you could introduce more latency if ethernet decides to fall back to a lower speed due to the kinks in the cable.  There is no minimum length for copper ethernet cabling.
- As you're probably aware, combinations of NICs / driver versions / OS can have a significant affect on intra-host latency.  I work for a network equipment manufacturer, and one of the guys in the office used to work as an applications engineer for [SolarFlare](http://www.solarflare.com/).  He claims that many of the Wall Street trading systems use SolarFlare's NICs due to the low latency SolarFlare engineers their products for; he also said SolarFlare's drivers give you user-space access to the NIC buffers.  Caveat: third-hand info, and I cannot verify myself.
- If you loop the frames to Machine A, set the source and destination mac-address to the burned-in-address on the NIC

Even if you need to receive a modified "pong" frame from Machine B, you could still use this topology and simply rewrite packet fields on the receive-side of your code in Machine A.  Put as many (or few) instrumentation points as you like in Machine A's "modules" to compare frame timestamps.

FYI:

The embedded systems I mentioned in my comments on your question are for measuring latency of network infrastructure, not end hosts.  This is the best method I can think of for instrumenting host latency.

Comment: +1. Excellent answer. This is exactly the kind of insights I was looking for. I'll definitely consider this approach

Answer (score 4):

As an off the shelf solution, I would suggest taking a look at Solace, Tibco and AMQP. These are all enterprise messaging frameworks used extensively in trading applications. [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) is open source and capable of handling throughputs of up to 100,000 messages per second. I am not sure of the latencies of other frameworks. There is a Java or C++ implementation of the AMQP message router. The C++ one of course returns higher performance.

**Edit** I've just heard of a new product called [UltraMessaging](http://www.informatica.com/us/products/messaging/) which can provide 7,000,000 messages per second throughput with Java, C++ or C# clients. Crikey.

Best regards,

Comment: Nice. This could be useful to stress test the system! Thanks

Comment: Sure could. 7m messages is crazy throughput!

Comment: Great answer, but I would like to add that ultramessaging can only perform sub-nano latency through shared memory. Also, 'x' per 'y' figures can be misleading without relative information/stats of system that 'x' was achieved on.